# Tkinter "entry widget" not taking any input

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created 2 seperate windows. One is home and another is for registration. When I run the registration module it works but when I try to go to the registration page from home and register, it doesn't take any input from fields.

when i tried to run the code from registration page itself , code runs and works as expected.No problem whatsoever. But it's not working whn I'm trying to open it from home page.

My code goes like this for home page :
''' python

```
import registration
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
c=registration.Register(root)
root = mainloop()
```

'''

For registration page
''' python

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector as mcon
con = mcon.connect(host = 'localhost',username = 'root',password ='root',database = 'park')
myc=con.cursor()

class Register:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry('800x800')
        self.e=StringVar()
        name = Label(self.root,text = "Enter name").pack()
        self.x=Entry(self.root,textvariable = self.e).pack()
        btn = Button(self.root,text = 'Save',command=self.exit).pack()

    def exit(self):
        self.y=self.e.get()
        myc.execute('insert into names values({})'.format(y))
        con.commit()
        self.root.destroy()
```

'''

When I try to run home page and enter name in register for and try to save it,  I get empty spaces in the table name in mysql. but it should have stored the value entered from entry field.

Comment: Read [The Tkinter Entry Widget - option textvariable](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: In your home script `root=mainloop()` ought to be `root.mainloop()`. The registration script has `self.y` holding the entry's value but your place holder takes `y`. Should change that to `.format(self.y)`. See if those work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you did wrong 
self.x=Entry(self.root,textvariable = self.e).pack()
instead 
self.x=Entry(self.root,textvariable = self.e)
self.x.pack()

now you can insert value to self.x